# How can I determine the number of bytes of each line of a file in java?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a very big text file. I want to determine the number of bytes of each line and save it in another file.

Comment: Which encoding is the file in? Which newline convention is used? Why do you need the number of bytes?

Comment: I assume you are creating an index, but how big is very big? A file of less than 100 MB is not so big these days.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Yes. I am creating an index file. My file is more than 800 MB. I have to do it to increase the search speed.

Comment: If its speed you want, can you load it into memory and have an index on the data in memory as well. It will take about 10 seconds to load, but access after that will be very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Using java.io.BufferedReader, you can easily read each line as a separate String. 
The number of bytes used by a line depends on the encoding used. For a simple ASCII encoding, you can simply use the length of the String, since each character takes up one byte. For multi-byte encodings like UTF-8, you would need a more complicated approach.

Comment: Thanks. I used the length of the string, but I have NullPointerException. Do you know how I can solve it? There are some empty lines in my file, and I think this causes such an exception.

Comment: @sylvester: when you hit the end of the file, BufferedReader's readLine method will return null to indicate that there's no more data to read. This is most likely the cause of your NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

The following code  extracts

```
   byte[] chunks  = null;
        BufferedReader  in = 
        new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path +"/"+filePath),"UTF-8"));
        String eachLine  = "";  
        while( (eachLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            chunks = eachLine.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(chunks.length);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a loop that:

1. Read one line in at a time.
2. Count the bytes
3. Save it to another file.

Comment: Where "count the bytes" is the problematic part. You can't do that when using the standard Java text I/O classes.

Comment: @larsmans, well it depends on what you define for your bytes.  The question is currently vague on that note so I also voted to close it.  Hopefully @sylvester will provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some definition of what constitutes a "line" in your big file, you can simply iterate over your file byte-by-byte and at each occurrence of a line end or line start you memorize the current index.

For example, if you have a unix text file (i.e. `\n` as line delimiter), this may look like this:

```
/**
 * a simple class encapsulating information about a line in a file.
 */
public static class LineInfo {
    LineInfo(number, start, end) {
       this.lineNumber = number;
       this.startPos = start;
       this.endPos = end;
       this.length = endPos - startPos;
    }
    /** the line number of the line. */
    public final long lineNumber;
    /** the index of the first byte of this line. */
    public final long startPos;
    /** the index after the last byte of this line. */
    public final long endPos;
    /** the length of this line (not including the line separators surrounding it). */
    public final long length;
}

/**
 * creates an index of a file by lines.
 * A "line" is defined by a group of bytes between '\n'
 * bytes (or start/end of file).
 *
 * For each line, a LineInfo element is created and put into the List.
 * The list is sorted by line number, start positions and end positions.
 */
public static List<LineInfo> indexFileByLines(File f)
    throws IOException
{

    List<LineInfo> infos = new ArrayList<LineInfo>();

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    int b;
    for(long index = 0, lastStart = 0, lineNumber = 0;
        (b = in.read()) >= 0 ;
        index++)
    {
        if(b == '\n') {
            LineInfo info = new LineInfo(lineNumber, lastStart, index);
            infos.add(info);
            lastStart = index + 1;
            lineNumber ++;
        }
    }
    return infos;
}
```

This avoids any conversion of bytes to chars, thus any encoding issues. It still depends on the line separator being `\n` - but there could be a parameter to give it to the method.

(For DOS/Windows files with `\r\n` as separator the condition is a bit more complicated, as we would either have to store the previous byte, or do a lookahead to the next one.)

For easier use, maybe instead of a list a pair (or triple) of `SortedMap<Long, LineInfo>` could be better.